# MathJax crashes in every page with equations

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

Is it just me? I keep getting this error when I open physics.stackexchange.com (and, for that matter, it also happens in math.stackexchange.com):

> MathJax no longer loads a default configuration file; you must specify such files explicitly. This page seems to use the older default config/MathJax.js file, and so needs to be updated. This is explained further at
>   http://www.mathjax.org/help/configuration

The result is that I can't see equations. Why is this happening? What can I do?

EDIT: I have had this issue with Internet Explorer 9, Internet Explorer 8, and Firefox 7.0.1. Perhaps I should also mention that my internet connection is dial-up (slow @ ~ 33kbps). However, I have no problems with other websites, such as Wikipedia, which is also heavy on equations.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it; perhaps this is specific to your browser version. In any case, it's definitely something the SE team needs to fix, not something that you can do anything about yourself. Could you edit the question to mention which browser and version (and operating system) you're using? http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/599 seems to be related.

Comment: Also try a [hard refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache). Ctrl+F5 (or sometimes Ctrl+R) does it on most browsers.

Comment: Occasionally MathJax problem can be resolved by clearing the cache.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: In Firefox 7.0.1, the problem usually "resolved" after a couple of refreshes (F5 refreshes). Now with I.E. 9 it doesn't go away with F5 nor Ctrl+F5, so I'm effectively unable to use Math.SE or phys.SE.

Comment: OK, I will bring this to the attention of the team. (Wikipedia doesn't use MathJax, they use images of equations, so you wouldn't have problems there.) Here's another related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113888/mathjax-no-longer-loads-a-default-configuration-file

Answer (score 2):

This should be resolved with the latest version of MathJax.